# Trouble with creating new variable based on mean in R

Tags: r, variables, new-operator

[image]

I have the following data and I am trying to get the mean duration (dur)

```
atusJoin3 %>%
    group_by(tuyear, agegroup) %>% 
    summarise(mean_dur = mean(dur, na.rm = T))
```

[image]

However, when I try to use the mean_dur in ggplot, it says that mean_dur is not found. Any idea, why mean_dur cannot be found?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be because the object is not updated by assigning (`<-`) to the same object (but that will overwrite the original object with summarised one, instead it is better to have a new object)

```
atusJoin_summary <-  atusJoin3 %>%
         group_by(tuyear, agegroup) %>% 
         summarise(mean_dur = mean(dur, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Now, we use `atusJoin_summary` as input data to `ggplot`

---

NOTE: If the intention is to create a new column in the data, use `mutate` inplace of `summarise`